# error while changing directory using crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

This is my script I am trying to rename the files in folder.

```
rename1.sh
----------
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/lanein1/WestonIN7pm/"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" && rename s/WestonIN/WestonIN7pm/ *.jpg
cd /home/lanein1/WestonOUT7pm/"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" && rename s/WestonOUT/WestonOUT7pm/ *.jpg
```

This is the error I get :

```
can't cd to /home/lanein1/scripts/rename1.sh
```

I don't understand why am  I getting this error

CRON ENTRY :

```
29 12 * * * cd /home/lanein1/scripts/rename1.sh >> /home/lanein1/scripts/rename2.log 2>&1
```

Comment: That error message doesn't correspond with the code you've provided. How exactly are you calling this script? (Please [edit] your question. Don't answer here in comments.)

Comment: the script is stored in /home/lanein1/scripts/reanme1.sh. Calling it through cron    29 12 * * * cd /home/lanein1/scripts/rename1.sh >> /home/lanein1/scripts/rename2.log 2>&1

Comment: Is `/home/lanein1/scripts/rename1.sh` a directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking to change directory to the script:

> ```
> cd /home/lanein1/scripts/rename1.sh >> /home/lanein1/scripts/rename2.log 2>&1
> ```

Perhaps you meant to run it:

```
/home/lanein1/scripts/rename1.sh >> /home/lanein1/scripts/rename2.log 2>&1
```